# Click event of template of a Custom Control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I have created a custom ContentControl in WPF and applied to it the following template:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:BdlUserControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:BdlUserControl">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="22"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="White">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                            <Button Content="Close" Width="50" Name="BtClose" Click="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=BtClose_Click}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The problem is that the BtClose doesn't call the method BtClose_Click declared in the code-behind of the custom control as shown below:

```
    public void BtClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test");
    }
```

The error is very generic:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
```

Any hints on why is that happening?

Comment: You cant Bind to an event handler, you will need to create a Command and bind the Buttons Command property to that command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF you can only bind to a `DependencyProperty`, In WPF Bottons have a Command property that you can Bind to. Commands are the MVVM way to handle events in WPF.

Here is a quick example of a Command binding in WPF.

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="50" Width="100" >
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyCommand = new MyClickCommand();
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public MyClickCommand MyCommand { get; set; }
}

public class MyClickCommand : ICommand 
{
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("click!");
    }
}
```

In the above example the `Execute` method in `MyClickCommand` will be called when you click on the button.

Now to make this a bit more user friendly you can use a `RelayCommand` implementations, this allows to pass delegates into the Command implementation which in most cases is the easiest way to use commands in WPF.

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="50" Width="100" >
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Click" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window 
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        MyCommand = new RelayCommand(MyMethod);
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public RelayCommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    private void MyMethod()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Click!");
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = p => execute();
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute();
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged 
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }
}
```

Example:

Comment: Can you show how to specifically bind commands to a custom control?